Finding the following nash equilbrium
It's been a while, since I have done some basic nash equilbirum stuff, so excuse me for a rather easy question.
We have the rather simplistic 2 by 2 bimatrix game:
row 1: $(0,0) (0,0)$ 
row 2: $(0,0) (-1,-1)$
The rows correspond to player 1 and the columns correspond to player 2. If we solely look at best responses, one would get three pure Nash Equilibria: (row 1,col 1), (row 1, col 2) & (row 2, col 1). However, it is easy to see that row 1 weakly dominates row 2 and column 1 weakly dominates column 2, so one could also argue that only row 1 and column 1 are played and we get a single Nash Equilibrium, namely (row 1, col 1).
I hope someone can shed some light on this, as I am struggling myself, albeit a very easy question.

There are three pure-strategy Nash equilibria, as the best-response reasoning shows.  As you say, however, in some sense the row 1, column 1 equilibrium is more "natural" in that it involves both players playing a weakly dominant strategy.  This makes it a weakly dominant strategy equilibrium, which is a refinement of Nash equilibrium.  (That is, every weakly dominant strategy equilibrium is a Nash equilibrium, but not vice versa -- why?)
TL;DR: The three strategy profiles are all Nash equilibria, but only the row 1, column 1 is a weakly dominant strategy equilibrium.

Thank you, @user806050!
